# Spanning text across two columns in a 3 column page in LaTeX?

Tags: columns

I can't seem to figure out how to span text across columns while preserving the continuance of the columns. I want to be able to accomplish this:[image: layout]

Where column 3 is a continuation of column 2 despite the text that spans the two columns. of Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What limitations do you have? Is this for a journal submission? Do the columns contain "floats"? What is included in the content that should span two columns?

Comment: Take a look at [`papertex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/papertex)

Comment: This looks like a job for flowfram!